# Angular2 Universal error Cannot find module '@angular/compiler/src/template_parser' after upgrading to RC5

Tags: angular, angular2-universal, angular2-compiler

Am using angular2 ,webpack and angular universal the project builds fine but I get the following error at runtime. Works fine with angular RC4

`Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler/src/template_parser'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/connecthealth/web-app/node_modules/angular2-universal/dist/node/platform/node.js:25:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular Universal hasn't updated yet to support RC5 yet. It's in the pipeline and should be coming out soon to support it.

[Github Issue](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/511)